# How to get the DateTime with ROUND value?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL select query I'm getting difference between two date time fields like `01:30:00`.

Now I need to convert as `1.5` hrs similarly for all.

Example:

- 01:15:00 to 1.25
- 01:30:00 to 1.5
- 01:45:00 to 1.75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TIME_TO_SEC`, try this:

```
select TIME_TO_SEC('01:30:00') / 3600
```

<kbd>[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/72237)</kbd>